# Use ID in a modal windows?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

In a modal window, how to retrieve and use the field id of the record for use in a mysql select? I can display it with  but i fon’t know how to use with php. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field.  This will pass the value in your modal form to your PHP that is processing the request.

```
<input type="hidden" name="id-i-need" value="32523456">
```

If you need to grab the ID field off the modal or something, you can reach for that with a data attribute and jQuery like this...

```
<div class="modal my-modal-thing" id="32523456" data-id="32523456">
```

data('id') here points to data-id in the modal div.

```
var idINeed = $('.my-modal-thing').data('id');
```

You can use jQuery to slap the value in the hidden field, if needed.  Likely you could just add this from the back end when building the page though.

```
$('input[name="id-i-need"]').val( idINeed );
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure.

My question was incomplete.

Inside a modal windows, I would like to put in the variable $this-id, the ID of the record to make a select MYSQL.
Like this :

$this-id=  ??? ; // ID of the record

$query = "SELECT * FROM storage WHERE id='$this-id' ";